# setDataSource with Uri causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, uri, media-player

Well, this is the `onClick` `method` of a `button`:

```
public void aggiungi (View v){

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("audio/*");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select"), PICK_AUDIO_REQUEST_CODE);

}
```

And outside I've handled the output:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == PICK_AUDIO_REQUEST_CODE){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri uri_to_use = data.getData();
            setAudioToButton(uri_to_use);
        }
    }

}
```

And here's the setAudioToButton `method` called

```
public void setAudioToButton(final Uri audio){
    PercentRelativeLayout percentRelativeLayout = (PercentRelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams(43, 12);
    layoutParams.addRule(PercentRelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    layoutParams.addRule(PercentRelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.quattro);
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = (PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams)button.getLayoutParams();
    PercentLayoutHelper.PercentLayoutInfo percentLayoutInfo = layoutParams1.getPercentLayoutInfo();
    percentLayoutInfo.heightPercent = 0.12f;
    percentLayoutInfo.widthPercent = 0.43f;
    percentLayoutInfo.topMarginPercent = 0.063f;
    percentLayoutInfo.leftMarginPercent = 0.007f;
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null){mediaPlayer.stop();}
            try {mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getBaseContext(), audio);} catch (IOException error){error.printStackTrace();}
            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
    button.setText("start");
    percentRelativeLayout.addView(button);
}
```

The problem is when I click on the new button to make it sound, I have a `NullPointerException`:

```
08-22 02:32:43.164 11880-11880/com.example.utente.usefulsounds E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.utente.usefulsounds, PID: 11880
                                                                             Theme: themes:{}
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(android.content.Context, android.net.Uri)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.example.utente.usefulsounds.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:182)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21158)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I am wondering why this happens, I can't understand

**

## EDIT:

**

I've put this in the `onCreate` `method`

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

But it didn't worked

Now I've tried in a different way: intead of passing an `Uri` to the `MediaPlayer`, I've passed a `filedescriptor`:

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null){mediaPlayer.stop();}
            File file = new File(audio.getPath());
            FileInputStream fileInputStream;
            try {
                fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                try {mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());} catch (IOException error){error.printStackTrace();}
            }catch (IOException ioe){button.setText("FILE ERROR");}

            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
```

The button appears with the text "select", so there isn't any problem with the `file` (otherwise it should have been "file error"), but when I click on that I still have a crash caused by a `NullPointerException` with `mediaPlayer`. Why this? I can't understand

Comment: and what is being returned by `data.getData();`?

Comment: @ScaryWombat It is returned a `uri`; to see it I've done this way: instead of `setText('start')` on the new `Button`, I put `setText(audio.toString())` and the `uri` that I get is `CONTENT://COM.ANDROID.PROVIDERS.MEDIA.DOCUMENTS/DOCUMENT/AUDIO%3A24283` (caps lock because it's in a button)

Comment: @ScaryWombat I added this on the onCreate method: `if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
        }` but still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## HERE'S THE ANSWER

Instead of doing a `setDataSource()` `method` you have to use simply a `create()` `method` :)

Eg.

```
 MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), yourAudioUri).start();
```

Happy coding and have fun :)